# On "Opinion based answers"

Tags: discussion

Hopefully this is not a duplicate, but I have some concerns about this topic, and would like to share them.

I am a relatively new active member of the community, and I saw that the "elder" community (like, over 10k reputation) is quite strict with the question formats. Let's take my question from few days ago:

[Why should I learn a microcontroller architecture?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/285404/why-should-i-learn-a-microcontroller-architecture)

I have actually quite benefitted from the answers, lots of experts have shared their experiences. I believe some other folks here have also enjoyed it, however it was put on hold for being "opinion based".

The only sensible reason I could think for that is "lots of people sharing their thoughts about topic so topic stays bumped frequently, which will keep other questions from being reviewed".

This site is home to many experienced engineers, and I actually want to benefit from their experiences as much as I can. And I believe this is needed more in EE, because EE subjects have steep learning curves, unlike programming for example, which you can try, fail, correct yourself and learn much faster.

Has there been any attempts to implement this kind of environment to Stack Exchange? If so, what were the repercussions?

Comment: You might want to read about that on meta.se. in short, the se community is largely based on facts and objectively correct/wrong things. We have not yet arrived in a postfactic world and hopefully never be. If you want opinions, there are lots of forums out there where you can get them. Se is no such place. We have a question and answer format, and don't do discussions. We aim to build a knowledge base in that format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange's purpose is to be an archive of well documented questions and answers and since quality is a vital factor, there are rather strict rules which should be followed by everyone.

"Primarily opinion based" means the answers will be mainly biased, subjective and that's not useful to the others. Technical problems, in general, demand crisp objectivity, don't you agree? There are too many things to consider in your case. It's the same as asking "Personally, would you learn microcontroller architecture?". There's no narrow array of solutions and it can depend on your goals. Again, too subjective , it's not going to help others. Well, it might, but by bearing in mind those who came here for the technical problems , one realises that it won't. Anyway, I mentioned why this format must restrict you like that.

If you narrow it down to something like "Why is microcontroller architecture vital for designing this kind of circuit", then nobody should close your question anymore(for this reason at least).

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> EE subjects have steep learning curves, unlike programming for example, which you can try, fail, correct yourself and learn much faster.

However, you can use your technique of learning here, too. Your question didn't fit in the format, that's how it happened. Nobody stops you from correcting this issue by making sure you keep in check the next posts you write :) .

Keep calm and carry on :)

Comment: The conundrum of opinion based answers is perfectly illustrated by your answer here. It's just your opinion. And remember that unless you're explaining what π is, all is but opinion and conceit.  It's just that people stretch their opinions differently for different questions.  If you review enough of them, you'll find that there's no concrete policy in force. It also changes with time as the herd evolves.

Comment: @Paul Uszak Thanks, I'll remember that